# SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: html

I'm getting

> SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

How to resolve it?

```
var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
```

Comment: What code is generating this error? Without knowing that, all I can suggest is to try an action that (the) Object *does* support.

Comment: Don't post **all** your code - instead, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way, you're not including parts of your code which are not relevant.